# Using Entities in JSF

Tags: java, jsf, jpa, jsf-2, jpa-2.0

I am writing a web application (Tomcat 7) so no JTA and want to display a list of projects including the tasks associated to each project in a JSF page.

There are 2 entities - Project which contains a Collection of Tasks. From my Managed Bean I  call a convenience method to retrieve all the active the Projects, then iterate (ui:repeat) over this Collection of Projects  and want to display the Tasks per Project. When I try t do this I get a Persistence Exception since the Persistence Context is no longer in scope.

Without creating backing beans of the Project and Task and without making use of an Extended Context what other options do I have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have your convenience method also fetch the tasks, for instance by joining that association in the query? If the task are already loaded, JPA won't need to fetch them when you access the collection.

Edit: The [JPA 2.0 specification](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/persistence-2.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/persistence-2_0-final-spec.pdf) writes in section 4.4.5.3:

> A FETCH JOIN enables the fetching of an association or element collection as a side effect of the execution of a query.
>
> The syntax for a fetch join is
>
> ```
> fetch_join ::= [ LEFT [OUTER] | INNER ] JOIN FETCH join_association_path_expression
> ```
>
> The association referenced by the right side of the FETCH JOIN clause must be an association or element collection that is referenced from an entity or embeddable that is returned as a result of the query.
>
> It is not permitted to specify an identification variable for the objects referenced by the right side of the FETCH JOIN clause, and hence references to the implicitly fetched entities or elements cannot appear elsewhere in the query.
>
> The following query returns a set of departments. As a side effect, the associated employees for those departments are also retrieved, even though they are not part of the explicit query result. The initialization of the persistent state or relationship fields or properties of the objects that are retrieved as a result of a  fetch  join  is determined by the metadata for that  class — in this  example, the Employee entity
>   class.
>
> ```
> SELECT d 
> FROM Department d LEFT JOIN FETCH d.employees
> WHERE d.deptno = 1
> ```
>
> A fetch join has the same join semantics as the corresponding inner or outer join, except that the related objects specified on the right-hand side of the join operation are not returned in the query result or otherwise referenced in the query. Hence, for example, if department 1 has five employees, the above query returns five references to the department 1 entity.
>
> The FETCH JOIN construct must not be used in the FROM clause of a subquery.

Comment: How would I write a query so that JPA loads the related data? Right now my query is simply "SELECT p FROM project p".

Comment: My answer now includes the relevant part of the spec, adapting the example it contains to your needs should be straightforward.

Comment: So awesome, was just reading the article actually. Thank you so coming back to update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

After some more thought and research I have come back to properly describe the situation I am in and then also to provide a way in which to resolve the problem.

What transpires is that the Project entity has the Tasks relationship specified as Lazy Loaded. JPA uses a proxy object that waits for a request to the collection before requesting the data to be fetched. This becomes a problem since we are trying to access the information after the Persistent context has detached the entities.

**Resolution:**

*Triggering Lazy Loading* - While the Persistent Context is still in scope call the collection getter and any other methods you would want the data for, this triggers the data to be fetched and added the the entity.

*Make the fetch type Eager* - Review the reasoning behind using lazy loading and change the fetch type to eager. "FetchType.EAGER"

*Fetch Joins* - Adding the association as part of the JP QL to be fetched together with the query. This optimizes the query and the association to be loaded in one call while still only returning a single Entity. "SELECT p FROM Project p LEFT JOIN FETCH p.tasks"

Hope this helps the next person to find a solution to their problem.

Answer (score 0):

Manually open an `EntityManager` (using the factory) and start a transaction, then commit it and close the entity manager.

But that's not a good option - take a look at something like CDI, Seam or Spring to manage transactions and sessions for you (if you don't want to use EJB3)